What happed if you undef undef_method using undef_method in Ruby?
I've just learned Ruby has special method called undef_method.
It literally undefines existing method.
With undef_method you can undefine < from Integer like following:
class Integer
  undef_method :<
end

begin
  puts 1 < 2
rescue Exception => exception
  puts exception
  puts 1.0 < 2
end

And the result is following:
undefined method `<' for an instance of Integer
true

This is understandable since Ruby itself is highly Object-Oriented and everything is an Object including its type system and so on.
But you can undefine undef_method to make impossible to undefine < from Integer.
class Module
  undef_method :undef_method
end

class Integer
  undef_method :<
end

begin
  puts 1 < 2
rescue Exception => exception
  puts exception
  puts 1.0 < 2
end

Now that undef_method itself is undefined you can't really undefine < from Integer.
temp.rb:6:in `<class:Integer>': undefined method `undef_method' for class Integer (NoMethodError)

  undef_method :<
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        from temp.rb:5:in `<main>'

So here's the question: How ruby can execute undef_method while it's getting undefined?
If Ruby was a complied language I assume Ruby loads the method first and executing self-undefining code so no problem!
But Ruby is interpreted language and does not load the codes before executing them.
I think this may cause the problem since Ruby can't tell what code to execute if the method is got undefined while it's executed.

Undefining doesn't "destroy" the method's source code. It just removes the method from the object's method table. This can even be undone: get a method handle via m = Module.instance_method(:undef_method) before calling undef_method and you can call Module.define_method(:undef_method, m) to add it back afterwards.

One thing to keep in mind is that while everything in Ruby may be an object the classes in the Ruby core are to a very large degree implemented in C and do not necissarily "follow the rules" of the language. That includes this method which is implemented as rb_mod_undef_method.


How ruby can execute undef_method while it's getting undefined?

Easily!
It might help to look at how methods work. Consider Kernel.puts(1 + 1).
Here's what happens, in order:

The receiver is evaluated.

Here, it's just a constant lookup for the name Kernel.


Method arguments are evaluated.

So, 1 + 1 results in 2.


The receiver's method table is searched.

Kernel.puts is found.


The method is called.

Kernel.puts is called with the argument 2.
The side effect occurs—it prints "2".
The return value (nil) is returned.



Now let's look at Module.undef_method(:undef_method) in the same way:

The receiver is evaluated.

Again, just a constant lookup, this time for the name Module.
Note that in your code sample, the receiver is discovered implicitly as part of the module evaluation. The effect is the same.


Method arguments are evaluated.

The argument is just the symbol literal :undef_method, which requires no additional evaluation.


The receiver's method table is searched.

Module.undef_method is found, because nothing has happened to it yet.


The method is called.

Module.undef_method is called with the argument :undef_method.
The side effect occurs—it removes the method from the receiver's method table.
The return value (Module) is returned.



As you can see, the "paradox" is easily explained by the fact that at the time of looking up the method, the method is still there. It is only removed in a separate step after it's already been looked up and called, and the act of removing the name "undef_method" from the method table doesn't affect the ability of the already-found method to finish executing.

So essentialy, undef_method does not actaully remove the code but only the symbol? And the code can be executed even when the reference to it is got removed, which is just a symbol on the lookup table, since it is still in use so gc can't just unload or remove the code.

I would say that it removes the link between the symbol/name and the underlying code. It may be different between various Ruby implementations. In C Ruby, the underlying code is a C function called rb_mod_undef_method, which will always remain in the memory of the running Ruby program regardless of what you do in the Ruby layer.
